# Display HTML inputs from string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, replace

I want to display HTML inputs from a string by replacing special texts.

HTML Code like below.

```
<h3 class="text-center" data-ng-bind-html="finalString"></h3>
```

JS Code like below.

```
        function convertStringToInput(){
            var string = ' Hi,Cricket match with !!!TEXT!!! on !!!DATE!!! Umpire is !!!TEXT!!! and price is !!!NUMBER!!! items.';

            var mapObj = {
                '!!!TEXT!!!': '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" data-ng-model="text" />',
                '!!!DATE!!!': '<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="date" data-ng-model="model" />',
                '!!!NUMBER!!!': '<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Number" data-ng-model="number" />'
            };
            string = string.replace(/!!!TEXT!!!|!!!DATE!!!|!!!NUMBER!!!/gi, function (matched) {
                return mapObj[matched];
            });

            $scope.finalString = string;
        }
        convertStringToInput();
```

Expected out is like !!!TEXT!!! replace with HTML input as textbox, !!!DATE!!! with datepicker and !!!NUMBER!!! with input type to number.

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: right now its displaying only Hi,Cricket match with on Umpire is and price is items.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(matched)` within your replace function?

Comment: !!!TEXT!!!
 !!!DATE!!! !!!TEXT!!!
!!!NUMBER!!!

Comment: And I'm assuming `console.log(mapObj[matched])` returns like an empty string or null or undefined or something?

Comment: no its display like. <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" data-ng-bind="text" />
<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="date" data-ng-bind="date" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" data-ng-bind="text" />
 <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Number" data-ng-bind="number" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161600/discussion-between-dixit-and-charlie-fish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include in HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Where X.Y.Z is your angularjs version

Then in javascript file in app module, add ngSanitize, for example:

```
angular.module('nameOfYourAppModule', ['ngSanitize'])
```

then inject $sce dependency in controller as such and add $scope.finalString = $sce.trustAshtml(string);

```
.controller('myController', function(
    $scope,
    $sce
) {
function convertStringToInput(){
            var string = ' Hi,Cricket match with !!!TEXT!!! on !!!DATE!!! Umpire is !!!TEXT!!! and price is !!!NUMBER!!! items.';

            var mapObj = {
                '!!!TEXT!!!': '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" data-ng-model="text" />',
                '!!!DATE!!!': '<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="date" data-ng-model="model" />',
                '!!!NUMBER!!!': '<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Number" data-ng-model="number" />'
            };
            string = string.replace(/!!!TEXT!!!|!!!DATE!!!|!!!NUMBER!!!/gi, function (matched) {
                return mapObj[matched];
            });


            $scope.finalString = $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
            console.log($scope.finalString);
        }
        convertStringToInput();
});
```

Source for further reading:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: thanks a lot. i make minor mistakes to convert html to trust as html.

Comment: You forgot to do $sce.trustAsHtml(string) ?